# History of separating milk and meat dishes

Tags: minhag, history, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

What are the origins of having separate milk and meat dishes? It seems to be a generally accepted practice, and there are many Acharonim that talk about it. Where was the idea first introduced and how has it developed over time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused about. Are you asking about the origins/mechanics of Ta'am K'Ikar? Or are you not sure what the level of obligation here is (you call it a "minhag", but I've never heard that term used here)?

Comment: By "separating between milk and meat dishes", do you mean putting them in different places?

Comment: @msh210 I assume the question means having them be different dishes, as opposed to just cleaning them and waiting a day.

Comment: @WAF Why assume he knows anything about Ben Yomo? I think this should be closed as unclear